# Nested C++ template with variadic

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I was wondering if it was possible to have nested C++ template and still be able to access the template values ?
To explain, here is what I currently have:

```
template <int first, int... tail>
struct ConstIntVector:ConstIntVector<tail...>
{};

template <int first>
struct ConstIntVector<first>
{}; 

template<int f1, int... t1>
int prod(const ConstIntVector<f1, t1...>, const int* a) {
    return f1 * (*a) + prod(ConstIntVector<t1...>(), a+1);
}
```

This way, I can access the `f1` value in my `prod` function. But I would like to do it like this:

```
template<ConstIntVector<int f1, int... t1>>
int prod(const int* a) {
    return f1 * (*a) + prod<ConstIntVector<t1...>>(a+1);
}
```

It is possible ?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @Useless `template argument 1 is invalid
 template <ConstIntVector<int f1, int... t1>>` (g++ -std=c++11)

Comment: So you want to move something from `()` to within `<>`?   Is there a reason, or do you just think it looks prettier?

Answer (score 4):

Partial template specializations aren't allowed for member functions. But you can use a helper struct:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T>
    struct prodHelper;

    template <int f1, int... t1>
    struct prodHelper<ConstIntVector<f1, t1...> >
    {
        static int eval(const int* a) { 
            return f1 * (*a) + prodHelper<ConstIntVector<t1...>>::eval(a+1);
        }
    };
}

template <typename T>
int prod(const int* a) {
    return detail::prodHelper<T>::eval(a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Actually, I knew I couldnt do that with function and I tried with struct, but I didnt knew I could write that :
template<typename T>
struct X<ATYPE<T>>()

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to utilize `ConstIntVector` structs to carry useful information:

```
template <int First, int... Tail>
struct ConstIntVector {
   constexpr static int value = First;
   using tail = ConstIntVector<Tail...>;
};

template <int First>
struct ConstIntVector<First> {
   constexpr static int value = First;
   using got_no_tail = void;
}; 

template <class CIV, typename CIV::tail* = nullptr>
int prod(const int* a) {
    return CIV::value * (*a) + prod<typename CIV::tail>(a+1);
}

template <class CIV, typename CIV::got_no_tail* = nullptr>
int prod(const int* a) {
    return CIV::value * (*a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just be aware, that recursion is neither necessary nor desirable to solve these kinds of TMP problems. First, it is better to simply define your vector like this:

```
template <int... Is>
struct ConstIntVector{};
```

That way you can have zero length vectors as well, which is convenient in handling edge cases (witness the fact that `std::array` can be length 0).

Next, lets write our product function. We'll modify it in two ways: first we'll infer the integer by trivially passing our `ConstIntVector` by value, and second we'll use pack expansions to avoid recursion.

```
template<int... Is>
int prod(const int* a, ConstIntVector<Is...>) {
    int index = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int [] temp = {(sum += (a[index++] * Is))...};
    return sum;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
using v2 = ConstIntVector<4,5,6>;
std::cerr << prod(v.data(), v2{});
```

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/968e2f9594c6b292

Link to example of highly optimized assembly: https://godbolt.org/g/oR6rKe.

Comment: Thanks for your concerns, but in my case, it is necessary and desirable because most of the ConstIntVector is actually fill with 0 and I expect the compiler to do the cleanup.
Will it does it with your way ?

Comment: @Viridya What's necessary and desirable for you is to use variadic integer template parameters. Once you are using those, these optimizations are quite trivial for a compiler to perform. I added a link showing some assembly in godbolt; you can see that it gets optimized perfectly using my approach.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
template<int I>
int prod(const int* a) {
    return I * (*a);
}

template<int I, int I2, int... Is>
int prod(const int* a) {
    return I * (*a) + prod<I2, Is...>(a + 1);
}
```